# Auxiliary polynomials with no roots in a prescribed set

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials

I would like to prove the following fact:

**Problem.** *Let $P(x)$ be a nonzero $d$-degree polynomial with integer coefficients which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, let $\beta_1,\ldots, \beta_t$ be distinct noninteger algebraic numbers and let $S$ be an infinite subset of positive integers. Then there exists an $m$-degree polynomial $Q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that
$$
P(x)Q(x)=\sum_{i\in S(d+m)}a_iz^i
$$
and $Q(\beta_i)\neq 0$, for all $i\in [1,t]$. Here, $S(x)=S\cap [1,x]$.*

In other words, I want to prove the existence of an auxiliary polynomial $Q(x)$ for which $P(x)Q(x)$ has zero coefficients whenever its index $i$ does not belong to $S$ (this is easy by using basic linear algebra, i.e., with help of linear homogeneous system) and moreover $Q(x)$ is nonzero for all $x$ in the prescribed set $\{\beta_1,\ldots, \beta_t\}$ (this is the part I was not able to deal).

Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try and show that you can find a sequence $Q_1, Q_2,..Q_n,..$ st each two have gcd $1$ and satisfy the condition on the coefficients of $PQ_j$; then the result follows since no more than $t$ of the $Q$ can vanish at least one of the betas by the gcd condition

Comment: @Conrad I already tried that, but since these $Q_j$'s come from a solution of a homogeneous linear system (in fact, its coefficients), then I was not able to ensure this $\gcd$ condition. Any suggestion to do this?

Comment: Alas, if $P(x)=x+1$ and $S$ is the set of even integers, then $PQ$ has root $-1$, and thereby $1$ as well (since it depends on $x^2$ only). So if $\beta_1=1$, you are in trouble...

Comment: @fedja  Actually, for my specific problem, $\beta$ is a non-integer algebraic number and $P(x)$ is irreducible. Sorry for that, I should include this in the statement.

Comment: The same $P$, $\beta=i$ and the set $S=\{4k\}$ is no better.